# My Angular index.html href is missing a subpath in the deployment

Tags: angular, deployment, kubernetes-helm

My app uses express and Angular for backend and frontend. They are not separated so the backend will send back the compiled index.html. In the compiled index.html, it'll try to download runtime.js, vendor.js and main.js.

```
<html lang="en">
  <app-main> Loading...</app-main>
  <script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

I deploy my app on kubernetes using helm chart. The url is `${Host}/my-app-name`. The issue is my compiled index.html will try to download those js files via `${Host}/main.js` instead of `${Host}/my-app-name/main.js` and get 404.

Here is my virtual-service.yaml in helm chart.

```
spec:
  gateways:
    {{ toYaml .Values.virtualService.gateways | indent 4 }}
  hosts:
    - ${Host}
  http:
    - name: {{ include "my-app-name" . }}
      match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "my-app-name"
      route:
        - destination:
            host: {{ include "my-app-name" . }}
            port:
              number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
```

How should I solve this issue? Chatgpt told me to hardcode my-app-name in base url in angular code. I don't want to do it because the url may change.